# Transforming a variable using the if- else if function

Tags: r, if-statement, data-wrangling

I have a data set that is that I want to calculate z scores by their year.

Example:

```
  Year  Score
   1999   120
   1999   132
   1998   120
   1997   132
   2000   120
   2002   132
   1998   160
   1997   142
   ....etc
```

What I want is:

```
  Year  Score  Z-Score
   1999   120  1.2
   1999   132  .01
   1998   120  -.6
   1997   132  1.1
   2000   120  -.6
   2002   132  0.5
   1998   160  2.1
   1997   142  .01
```

I have used the following code:

```
DF$ZScore<-if (DR$Year== 1997){
((DF$Score-220)/20)
} else if ((DR$Year== 1998){
((DF$Score-222)/19)
}...
}else{
((DF$Score-219)/21)
}
```

This is not working and I cannot figure out why. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the gapminder data for simplicity, and also the built in scale function. You might want to build your own function to apply depending on exactly how you want to scale it.

this is a little clukly, but beause you want per year scaling, then you could group by the year and make a nested data frame.
Then using purr, you could go into each data.frame within a year, and scale the variable you want.
Then you would unnest the data again, and the variable would be scaled within each year.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gapminder)

gapminder::gapminder %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(data = map(data, 
                    ~ mutate_at(.x, vars(lifeExp, pop), 
                                      list(scale = scale)))) %>% 
  unnest(data)
#> # A tibble: 1,704 x 8
#> # Groups:   year [12]
#>     year country continent lifeExp    pop gdpPercap lifeExp_scale[,…
#>    <int> <fct>   <fct>       <dbl>  <int>     <dbl>            <dbl>
#>  1  1952 Afghan… Asia         28.8 8.43e6      779.           -1.66 
#>  2  1952 Albania Europe       55.2 1.28e6     1601.            0.505
#>  3  1952 Algeria Africa       43.1 9.28e6     2449.           -0.489
#>  4  1952 Angola  Africa       30.0 4.23e6     3521.           -1.56 
#>  5  1952 Argent… Americas     62.5 1.79e7     5911.            1.10 
#>  6  1952 Austra… Oceania      69.1 8.69e6    10040.            1.64 
#>  7  1952 Austria Europe       66.8 6.93e6     6137.            1.45 
#>  8  1952 Bahrain Asia         50.9 1.20e5     9867.            0.154
#>  9  1952 Bangla… Asia         37.5 4.69e7      684.           -0.947
#> 10  1952 Belgium Europe       68   8.73e6     8343.            1.55 
#> # … with 1,694 more rows, and 1 more variable: pop_scale[,1] <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I had already used the split function and divided my df into a list by years. Then I converted each list element into a df on its own, added my new variable that was specific for that year, then rbinded all of these new dfs together. Not the quickest way, but it got done. I have been trying this code, I can't seem to get it right...Thank you for your help though!